# PHP - Autoloading classes : Dynamically instantiate objects when needed

Tags: php, singleton, autoload

This maybe get a little bit complicated so I try to explain it in the easiest way possible.
Consider `source.php` which holds a piece of code which may or may not need some classes that are defined in `class1.php`, `class2.php` and so on.

**source.php** - typical autoloading

```
// Simple autoloader, nothing fancy
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        $requested_file = strtolower($class) . '.php';
        if (file_exists($requested_class)) {
                require_once($requested_class);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unable to load $class.");
        }
    });
...
$class1 = new Class1();
class1->doSomething();
...
$class8 = new Class8();
class8->doSomethingElse();
```

Basically I want to omit object instantiation  and use objects right away like this:

**source.php** - what I want to achieve

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
   ...
    });
...
$class1->doSomething();
...
$class8->doSomethingElse();
```

Why you ask? Well, I programmed a custom CMS couple of months ago using Singleton pattern, I defined all classes as Static and used them like this:

**source.php** - what I do now

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
   ...
    });
...
Class1::doSomething();
...
Class8::doSomethingElse();
```

Think of a over 100 source and class files, I answer some comments here before someone point them out in comment section.

- **Why did you use static classes at first place?**
  Because at that time I thought with this little trick only requested classes will be loaded and it will save a lot of memory and CPU consumption.
- **Then why you want to switch from static classes?**
  Our project manger has read some articles about static classes versus one instantiation of a class and concluded that we have to switch because it will has a significant performance improvement (though I personally know drawbacks of static classes but I do not believe that there will be a significant improvement).
- **Just instantiate an object at the end of each class file.** It wont help because instantiated object in class files still will not be recognizable in sourde files.
- **Find the first time that you have used a class and instantiate an object there.** Can't be done, because this source files are included in each other in no particular way by other developers i.e. `source1.php` and `source2.php` are both included in `source3.php` and both use the same class.
- **What to you suggest?**
  Is there anyway that we could catch php when encounters an undefined variable used as object (like spl_autoload_register) and then load the requested class accordingly?

---

### **TL;DR**

How to dynamically autoload a class when an instance of that class is used, which means only requested classes be included instead of blindly include them all?

Comment: How will you know what type of class $object is if you don't assign it a particular type?

Comment: to broad, there are many books on this

Comment: @FatDog47 what kind of class would get loaded if I said $class1->doSomething();

Comment: @orangepill: easily, class1 is an instantiation of Class1. I used singleton pattern so just by capitalizing first letter of instantiation we get the class name.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but in php 5.4 you can do `(new Class1)->doSomething()`

Comment: @dagon: Could you provide any source link?

Comment: This is both bad and wrong. Have your project manager look up articles on `Dependency Injection Containers`, `Service Locators`, and why overuse of singletons are bad.

Comment: @RobW: Then it will be impossible to use that instantiated object in the rest of the code unless we hold its address in another variable, which is kinda like instantiating a object in regular way.

Comment: Why not use a more traditional singleton pattern? Something like this:  `Class8::getInstance()->doSomething();` You can assign the value from getInstance to a variable if you want, but you don't have to.

Comment: @jcsanyi: Greet idea, that would do. Thanks. Lets just wait see is there any other solution without using any static member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're describing is not possible in PHP, and would not be recommended even if it was possible.

Instead, I'd suggest a more traditional singleton pattern.
In your class:

```
class Class8 {
    private $_instance = null;
    public static getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new Class8();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // rest of class here, with no static
}
```

Then you can call `Class8::getInstance()` whenever you want, and you'll get the same instance of the class every time that it's called.